# NextJS fetching DATA from MongoDB using getServerSideProps

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am tryin to fetch user data from MongoDB database using getServerSideProps with dynamic path. Here is my code.

```
import dbConnect from 'lib/dbConnect'
import User from 'models/User' 

export default function refID({user}){
return(
    <>
    <p>USERID:{user.userID}</p>
    <p>USERNAME:{user.userName}</p>
    </>
);
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
await dbConnect()
const user = await User.findOne({userID}).lean() 
user._id = user._id.toString()

return { props: { user } }
}
```

I have tried using hardcoded data.ie `'userID:S7L4SU'` which works fine except that for only that one user.

How can I define the **userID** such that it fetches data for that ID ?I have tried couple of methods which resulted to errors..

Sample path:`http://localhost:3000/p/[userID]`

How will i get around for dynamic path to work for all users in the DATABASE??Help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const { userID } = ctx.query;
  await dbConnect()
  const user = await User.findOne({userID}).lean() 
  if (user !== null) {
    user._id = user._id.toString()
  }
  return { props: { user } }
}
```

Comment: Got this : `ReferenceError: query is not defined`

Comment: Please try updated code

Comment: It works!! Thanks buddy! I've been stuck there whole day.

Comment: Should I do the casting manually?! Imagine if I'm using "find", should I loop over all the users returned from the query and cast each ID manually?